# setting a flag in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, flags

MODNOTE: I used the {} tags to format the code, but it looks horrible. I'm trying to fix it now.

My specific questions are:

1. I'm setting a flag with a javascript variable. Is the way I'm doing it a reasonable approach?
2. I've researched this a bit on this site and elsewhere, and noted that flags can be "set" (1) in an array, (2) in a hidden HTML element, (3) in a cookie. I've seen nothing about setting a flag with .data().
3. Is there an "elegant", "standard", "accepted" way to set a flag for use on ONE page to make a decision in an if/else statement? How do YOU set flags in situations like this?

My code is below:

1. After "ready" set flag to "not set".
2. Click on a button to input new info into a table - flag is set "add"
3. Click on a row in a table of existing data - flag is set to "update"
4. If flag is "add" use ajax to add to table, if flag is "update" update a row in the db.

### CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var flagaddupdate = "notset";

  $("#onsetdate").mask("99-99-9999");
  $("#entrydate").mask("99-99-9999");       
  $("#uonsetdate").mask("99-99-9999");
  $("#uentrydate").mask("99-99-9999");      

  $(function(e) {
  $("#reaction").autocomplete({
         source: [ "none", "rash/hives", "Nausea/vomiting", "Diarrhea", "Headache", "Dizziness" ],
         minlength: 1
                               });
                });


    $("#addintoleranceenterbutton").click(function() {
      flagaddupdate = "add";
      $( "#addintolerancetable" ).dialog(
                                         {height: 320,
                                           width: 450,
                                           modal: true}
                                         );
      });//end of add click

    $("#patienttable tr").click(function() {
      flagaddupdate = "update";
      $( "#addintolerancetable" ).dialog(
                                         {height: 320,
                                           width: 450,
                                           modal: true}
                                         );
      uniqueid = $(this).find("#uniqueid").html();
      $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "readintolerancebackend.php",
              data: {uniqueid: uniqueid},
              dataType : 'json',
              })
                .done(function(result){
                       $('#namegen').val(result['namegen']);
                       $('#nametrade').val(result['nametrade']);
                       $('#reaction').val(result['reaction']);
                       $('#onsetdate').val(result['onsetdate']);
                       $('#entrydate').val(result['entrydate']);       
                       if ( result['status'] == "Active" )
                          { $('#active').prop('checked',true);}
                          else
                          { $('#inactive').prop('checked',true);}
                                      })
                .always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                                                          console.log(data, textStatus, jqXH);
                                                          });
      });//end of update click

          $("#submitbutton").click(function() {
            var namegen    = $('#namegen').val();
            var nametrade  = $('#nametrade').val();
            var reaction   = $('#reaction').val();
            var onsetdate  = $('#onsetdate').val();
            var entrydate  = $('#entrydate').val();
            var status     = $('input:radio[name=status]:checked').val();

          if (flagaddupdate == "add")
            {
             $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "addintolerancebackend.php",
                     data: {
                            namegen: namegen, nametrade: nametrade, reaction: reaction,
                            onsetdate: onsetdate, entrydate: entrydate, status: status
                            }
                     })
                       .done( function( msg ) {alert( "Intolerance Added" + msg );
                                         window.location = "intolerance.php";
                                         })
                       .always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                                                           console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
                                                           });  
            }
            else
            { do another ajax call};
```

Comment: Usually we call that a "state", not a "flag" (which would be boolean).

Comment: Ok, "state". Is this the way you would set and use a "state"?